# Inserting data to local storage failed

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, return

Activity Code

```
    private SQLiteDatabase mSqliteDatabase;

public static String TABLE_CHAT_DATA = null;
public static final String KEY_SENDER = "Sender";
public static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "Message";
public static final String KEY_TIME = "Time";
public static final String KEY_SEEN = "Seen";
public static final String KEY_TIMER = "Timer";
public static final String KEY_TYPE = "Type";
```

onCreate

```
 mSqliteDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    TABLE_CHAT_DATA = MessageRecieverId;
    String mQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_CHAT_DATA + "(" + KEY_SENDER + " TEXT, " + KEY_MESSAGE
            + " TEXT, " + KEY_TIME + " TEXT, " + KEY_SEEN + " TEXT, " + KEY_TIMER + " TEXT, " + KEY_TYPE + "TEXT)";
    mSqliteDatabase.execSQL(mQuery);
```

Inserting Data

```
     MainData helper = new MainData(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_SENDER, "Me");
        contentValues.put(KEY_MESSAGE, messageText);
        contentValues.put(KEY_TIME, String.valueOf(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP));
        contentValues.put(KEY_SEEN, "No");
        contentValues.put(KEY_TIMER, "TYPE");
        contentValues.put(KEY_TYPE, "Text");

        long returnVariable = db.insert(TABLE_CHAT_DATA,null,contentValues);
        if (returnVariable == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Nope", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //-1 means there was an error updating the values
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

The Toast is showing Nope which means the return value is -1 which means it failed. I have gone through the same code numerous times but unable to figure out why its failing.

Table created successfully and while inserting data none of them are null because i tried inserting hardcoded data too but still failed. Also tried **MainData helper = new MainData(this);** instead of **getApplicationContext()** but still not working. Can someone point out Where i have gone wrong?

Error after trying insertOrThrow

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.appmaster.akash.messageplus, PID: 25418
                                                                             android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table eR3C1LXJhzaK3fPzCpcuTuz9jZB3 has no column named Type (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO eR3C1LXJhzaK3fPzCpcuTuz9jZB3(Sender,Time,Type,Message,Seen,Timer) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1472)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1369)
                                                                                 at com.appmaster.akash.messageplus.Chat.sendMessage(Chat.java:843)
                                                                                 at com.appmaster.akash.messageplus.Chat.access$800(Chat.java:79)
                                                                                 at com.appmaster.akash.messageplus.Chat$5.onClick(Chat.java:561)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

A bit confused because it shows no such column but in the creation it clearly has the column

Comment: Please provide error that is shown in Logcat. Also please specify if you are using Content Providers to access your data in the database or you access this directly.

Comment: There is no error in the logcat... im just checking whether the data is uploaded through long variable and it shows -1 which means its not uploaded @Domin

Comment: Try using `insertOrThrow` instead of insert and catch/log the exception.

Comment: hold on let me try @Andy

Comment: Check the edit @Andy

Comment: @LaylaMcKenzy (in the create...) " TEXT, " + KEY_TYPE + "TEXT")   - missing blank needed before 'TEXT' so you probably have a column named TypeTEXT.

Comment: Omg... iv spent the last 5 hours trying to figure out and its all cuz of a damn Space... Thanks a ton man @Andy